# How can I serialize a class which is not marked serializable

Tags: c#, serializable

I am using a class A from my co-worker and it is not marked as serializable. I tried to serialize it and got an error.

I tried to derive a class B from class A and marked class B as serializable. However, the compiler still complain that A is not serializable. Is there any workabout other than asking my coworker to modify the code to mark it as serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting that class a into B does not work.

You should avoid marking any class as serializable that is not a DTO (Data transfer object) or message class.In Other cases you can mark a class as serializable.